# svg marker does not work in IE9-10

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

Working first time on svg.
  I have following svg definition for an 'arrow-like' path

```
<defs>
    <marker id="start" refX="1" refY="5" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" markerWidth="17" markerHeight="11" orient="auto">
        <path id="conditional"   d="M 0 6 L 8 1 L 15 5 L 8 9 L 1 5" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <path id="default" d="M 5 0 L 11 10" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
    </marker>
    <marker id="end" refX="15" refY="6" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" markerWidth="15" markerHeight="12" orient="auto">
        <path id="arrowhead" d="M 0 1 L 15 6 L 0 11z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" />
    </marker>
</defs>
<g id="edge">
    <path id="bg_frame" d="M10 50 L210 50" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" marker-start="url(#start)" marker-end="url(#end)" />
    <text id="text_name" x="0" y="0" oryx:edgePosition="startTop"/>
</g>
```

But it does not show arrow at the end of path in IE 9 or IE 10

Does 'triangle' not supported in IE or Problem in the code?

An example here, http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/painting/marker.svg too does not work in IE.

Help Please, it is the only point my workflow editor has stuck.

Link result

[image]

My code's result in FF is:

[image]

And code result in IE is(there is no arrow, no square at the end of arrow):

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The problem is already reported to Microsoft as xdhmoore wrote in his answer:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/801938/dynamically-updated-svg-path-with-a-marker-end-does-not-update

There is a fiddle where the problem is shown:
http://jsfiddle.net/EEYZZ/

```
   //if (isIE10 || isIE11) {
       var parent = p1.parentNode;
       parent.removeChild(p1);
       parent.appendChild(p1);
   //}
```

My workaround is to manuelly remove the node from DOM and add it again, this will update the node as wanted... Don't speak about performance and stuff, but I think currently there is no better way to do it. (http://jsfiddle.net/kaljak/5zTv9/3/)

Comment: +1 for the workaround.  Got me thinking you might be able to swap between two markers instead of removing the node: http://jsfiddle.net/2Qh3g/1/.  Seems to be more jittery than your solution, however.

Comment: +1 for the workaround. But you do not need to remove the SVG element. `parent.appendChild(child)` is enought to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

One problem in IE seems to be that `marker` inherits the `stroke`, `stroke-width` and `fill` properties (contrary to the standards).

However, this can be worked around by setting the stroke properties explicitly.

Consider the problem with

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/painting/marker.svg

By setting the marker `stroke="none"` and `fill="black"` the rendering seems fine:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmYzGE

Note: I have tested this only in IE11. My guess is that it will work at least in IE10 as well. Any information on this very welcome.

Comment: This seems to work for me, and (IMO) should be chosen as the preferred answer, because it is such an easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same Problem and it was causing me quite some headache - I really can't understand why Microsoft doesn't fix that. I decided to replace the markers with custom paths which has the nice side-effect that you can e.g. change the fill or the color at runtime using JavaScript.

I create my svg using d3, the edge has class 'edge-path' and the tip has class 'edge-tip'. Both paths are children of an svg:g. The edge itself is a spline, so for rotating the tip I take the slope of the last 10 pixels. This is pretty much the code which is used to update the arrow, works in IE9-11:

```
edge.select('path.edge-tip')
     // the shape of the tip  
     .attr('d', 'M0,0L10,5L0,10Z')
     // move the tip to the end of the edge and rotate.
     .attr('transform', function(d) {
         var parent = d3.select(this).node().parentNode,
             path = d3.select(parent).select('path.edge-path').node(),
             pathLength = path.getTotalLength(),
             point1 = path.getPointAtLength(Math.max(0, pathLength - 10)),
             point2 = path.getPointAtLength(pathLength),
             vect = { x: point2.x - point1.x, y: point2.y - point1.y }
             l1 = vect.x * vect.x + vect.y * vect.y;
         l1 = Math.sqrt(l1);
         var angle = Math.acos(vect.x / l1);
         angle = 360 * (angle / (2*Math.PI));
         if (vect.y < 0) {
             angle = 360 - angle;
         }
         return 'translate(' + point1.x + ',' + (point1.y - 5) + ') rotate (' + angle +' 0 5)';
    });
```

Maybe it helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues moving lines dynamically with markers.  They show up fine on pageload, but don't move when the lines x/y attributes are changed.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f772aab3-5ce3-4367-8eec-4fe58ad94b14/urgent-serious-bug-svg-marker-is-not-updating-when-changing-the-lines-xy-in-ie10?forum=iewebdevelopment

http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/801938/dynamically-updated-svg-path-with-a-marker-end-does-not-update

Answer (score 0):

This appeared to render fine in IE10 for me (diamond shape on the left and triangle on the right).

However there *are* some known issues with markers in IE.  For instance, IE doesn't support markerUnits="strokeWidth".

Comment: 'this' here is link example or my code? I am attaching image of what I got for link result in IE10. `makerUnits=userSpaceOnUse` is supported?

Comment: `markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` works fine in IE (in my experience). It is only `"strokeWidth"` that is broken.  As I said, your main example works for me in IE.  Can you post a pic of what you are getting?

Comment: I would need to see the SVG code for your new example.  The initial example (with the single line) works fine in IE10, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Laying another group around the element and defining within this group the markers works in MS Edge and others.

```
     <g id="maszlinie" style="marker-start: url(#pf2); marker-end: url(#pf)">
     <g id="bline" transform="translate(0,-20)">
        <line class="masz" y2="365" y1="365" x2="415" x1="15">
     </g>
     </g>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get markers to work in IE11, but in Edge they work. The trick is for inline SVGs you need to use `xml:id` for the markers instead of just `id`.

Edit: in fact `anything:id` works. Not sure why.

Edit 2: Ugh. That breaks the SVG in Chrome. You can duplicate the ID: `id="foo" edge_sucks:id="foo"`.

Edit 3: Hmm scratch that it seems to work in Edge after all. No idea what is going on.