# Oryx Editor SVG marker end (sequence arrow) does not work in IE 10 and 11 in oryx editor (JBPM)

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, jbpm

I am using Oryx Editor with in JBPM 6. When I use Oryx Editor in FireFox it doesn't have any Issue, but in IE 10, 11  SVG sequence lines are not displaying the Arrow in the last.

Open the Oryx Editor (Workflow Designer) in IE (10 or 11) 
Click Start Event (drag to editor) 
Hover the Start Event and click the Task small box - it will add a task box
You will see the connecting lines in the end don't have arrows.

Please suggest me what is wrong 
Thanks

Comment: I could not add images because of less score.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kaljak/5zTv9/3/ this solution is work around but I need to do it in Oryx Editor.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654578/svg-marker-does-not-work-in-ie9-10   This question is related to this but not helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working finally I referred few of link in comments section and change the code in oryx editor svgmarker.js file inside the update function that is defined at line number 173.
File path : oryx /editor/client/scripts/Core/SVG/svgmarker.js
Code added inside the update function:

```
    var cusMarkerID = document.getElementById(this.element.id);

    //update old values to prepare the next update
    this.oldRefX = this.refX;
    this.oldRefY = this.refY;
    this.oldMarkerWidth = this.markerWidth;
    this.oldMarkerHeight = this.markerHeight;

    this.element.parent = cusMarkerID.parentNode;
    this.element.parent.removeChild(cusMarkerID);
    this.element.appendChild(cusMarkerID);
```

It was suggested in microsoft help docs for IE.